# jquery help need - put data only under same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps

So, making a form where have more than 1  address search box.
Using jquery google autocomplete address search.
with this jquery plugin:
**ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete**

trying to get details data to different input box like this:
**ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/form.html**

```
$(".addressinputclass").geocomplete({
  details: ".thisisparentclass",
  detailsAttribute: "data-geo"
});
```

this is html:

```
            <div class="thisisparentclass">
                <input type="text" name="address1" class="addressinputclass" />
                <input type="text" name="writepostcodehere" placeholder="Post code" data-geo="postal_code" />
                <input type="text" name="writecountryhere" placeholder="Country Name" data-geo="country" />
            </div>
```

but problem now, when it is more than one address input box, other information boxes get last address information.
you can check example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/kosmspLm/

any help there?

---

update:
Thanks for the help from both Lesha Ogonkov & Tushar Gupta.
I got solution for my question.
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ub2325n2/)</kbd>

**Solution**

```
$this.closest(".thisisparentclass");
```

Find the current parent with class `thisisparentclass` of the address input, so that `detailsAttribute` are only filled for the current selection .

```
$(function () {
    $(".addressinputclass").each(function () {//run each loop
        var $this = $(this); //cache your selector, this refers to the current element
        $this.geocomplete({ //attach auto-complete to the current element 
            details: $this.closest(".thisisparentclass"), //get the closest elements with class thisisparentclass
            detailsAttribute: "data-geo" //attach data attribute
        });
    });
});
```

**Problem**

you are attaching to all the elements having the class `thisisparentclass`, so when you select the addess it fills all the boxes and changes previous selections.

```
$(".addressinputclass").geocomplete({
  details: ".thisisparentclass", //you are attaching to all the elements having this class
  detailsAttribute: "data-geo"
});
```

Comment: wow! i tried with $(this).closest(".thisisparentclass"), but it was not successful, didn't think about each loop. many thanks for the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass selectors to plugin

http://jsfiddle.net/kosmspLm/2/

```
$(function(){
  $('.addressinputclass[name="address1"]').geocomplete({
    details: $($(".thisisparentclass").get(0)),
    detailsAttribute: "data-geo"
  });
});
```

If you need few fields to work, i think you need to loop over your containers, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $(".thisisparentclass").each(function() {
      var suggest, details;

      details = $(this);
      suggest = details.find('.addressinputclass');

      suggest.geocomplete({
        details: details,
        detailsAttribute: "data-geo"
      });
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kosmspLm/3/